# How to use imported namespace as a typescript interface?

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble figuring out how to use imported names in a typescript interface/type.

I have a few files that export different types...

###### foo.js

```js
const ObjA = {}
const ObjB = {}
export {
  ObjA,
  ObjB
}
```

###### bar.js

```js
export const Bar: { [key: string]: string } = {
  stringA: 'some string',
  stringB: 'some string',
}
```

I want to import those files, and use the imported values to create a new typescript object definition...

```js
import * as Foo from 'foo';
import { Bar } from 'bar';

type MyTypes = keyof Foo; // this would be ObjA, ObjB

type MyType = {
  [typeName in MyTypes]: keyof Bar; // this would be stringA, stringB
};
```

I want to enforce an object to have a key name using the exported values from one imported file, and the values from the exported values of another. something like...

```js
const newObject: MyType = {
  ObjA: 'stringA',        // passes
  fooKey: 'stringB',      // fails due to invalid key
  ObjB: 'fail',           // fails due to invalid value
  barKey: 'randomValue',  // fails due to invalid key & value
}
```

Comment: Example in `bar.js` won't compile. Do you mean something like `export const Bar = { stringA: 'some string', stringB: 'some string' }` ?

Comment: yea sorry i was pseudo-coding all the examples... just enough to get the idea across. i'll update it to be more clear tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Foo` and `Bar` are values. [`typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator) can be used to get their type:

```
type MyTypes = keyof typeof Foo;

type MyType = {
  [typeName in MyTypes]: keyof typeof Bar;
};

// Or just:
// type MyType = Record<MyTypes, keyof typeof Bar>
```

> `typeof` operator can be used in a type context to refer to the type of a variable or property

Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but in this case `MyType` will resolve to:

```
{
  ObjA: "stringA" | "stringB";
  ObjB: "stringA" | "stringB";
}
```

Comment: ah i've never seen the `keyof typeof` combo! although it only seems to work for Foo. `keyof Bar` throws "Bar refers to a value, but is being used as a type. did you mean typeof?", and the type definition is "string | number | symbol". maybe because of the way it's imported?

Comment: Here's an example on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/green-platform-xrent?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: ah, its because Bar has an existing definition of `Bar: { [key: string]: string }`. i updated the example and forked the sandbax https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-resonance-v9ruk . it strangely makes MyType values resolve to string | number

Comment: Well, you need to remove the explicit typing because it overrides the inferred value

Comment: that isn't my code, so i won't be able to remove it :/